# import this library in my project android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to import this library in my project. What is the proper way to do it? I'm trying to import it but failed.

Comment: minus 1 for not including the crash log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your styles.xml add these two lines in your theme , by this you can use tool bar instead of action bar

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I got another issue after i applied your solution. I have a setting activity and that one is not using base activity when i choose my setting activity in my navigation drawer the app is crashed

Comment: My setting activity is using getsupportactionbar